# Text Overlay On a Video (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, aforge

You may have seen this question on other forum but i still can't resolve this issue.
I manage to get the text overlay for few second but after that it disappears and display following image (it does not stop the program):

[image: error displayed photo]

i have a code like this when i got above error:

```
    Private Sub CAPTURAR(sender As Object, eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs)

    If ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black Then 'if n ot recording......

        BMP = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'PONE LOS DATOS EN EL BITMAP
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'PUT THE DATA IN THE BITMAP
        BMP.Dispose()

        'insert text overlay
        If BMP IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
            g.DrawString(New String("new"), New Font("Arial", 16), Brushes.White, New Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 50))
            g.Dispose()
        End If

    Else ' SI ESTAS GRABANDO...

        BMP = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) ' If YOU ARE RECORDING
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'PRESENTS THEM AT THE PICTURE BOX
        ESCRITOR.WriteVideoFrame(BMP) 'KEEP THEM IN THE MEMORY

    End If

End Sub
```

The full code is here: [AForge WebCam Recorder](http://visualbasictutoriales.blogspot.com/2015/03/webcam-video-aforge-con-visual-basic.html)

Thanks in advance
 -

14 Jan 2020: updated code and i got the overlay on the video perfectly:

```
 Private Sub ButtonVIDEO_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonVIDEO.Click

    If ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black Then 'YOU ARE NOT RECORDING VIDEO
        SaveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = ".avi" 'SAVE AS AVI FILE
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim ANCHO As Integer = CAMARA.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width 'DEFINE THE WIDTH OF THE PHOTOGRAPH
            Dim ALTO As Integer = CAMARA.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height 'DEFINE THE HIGH OF THE PHOTOGRAPH
            'CREATE THE FILE FOR DATA WITH SAVED PARAMETERS
            ESCRITOR.Open(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, ANCHO, ALTO, NumericUpDownFPS.Value, VideoCodec.Default, NumericUpDownBRT.Value * 1000)
            ESCRITOR.WriteVideoFrame(BMP)    'START SAVING DATA
            ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Red 'SO WE KNOW THAT HE'S RECORDING

        End If

    Else
        ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black 'YOU ARE RECORDING
        ESCRITOR.Close()    'STOP SAVING DATA
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub CAPTURAR(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs)
    Me.Invoke(CType(Function()



                        If ButtonVIDEO.BackColor = Color.Black Then 'IF YOU ARE NOT RECORDING ......

                            BMP = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'PUT THE DATA IN THE BITMAP
                            PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap) 'PRESENTS THEM AT THE PICTURE BOX

                            'insert text overlay

                        Else 'IF YOU ARE RECORDING ...
                            Try
                                BMP = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)     'PUT THE DATA IN THE BITMAP
                                PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), Bitmap)  'PRESENTS THEM AT THE PICTURE BOX
                                ESCRITOR.WriteVideoFrame(BMP)  'KEEP THEM IN THE MEMORY
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try
                        End If
                        If BMP IsNot Nothing Then
                            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
                            g.DrawString(New String("new"), New Font("Arial", 16), Brushes.White, New Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 50))
                            g.Dispose()
                        End If
                        Me.Invoke(CType(Function()


                                        End Function, MethodInvoker))
                        GC.Collect()
                    End Function, MethodInvoker))

End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't have an empty Catch like that unless you want the program to ignore whatever went wrong. Comment out the Try..Catch lines. It looks like you have forgotten to dispose of the bitmap, so maybe it is filling the RAM and that is interfering with its operation. (Useful info: [Using Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).)

Comment: i tried that as well but the it still give me the same result. see my edited  question.

Comment: It is the Red Cross of Failure, happen when the OnPaint() method of a control suffers an unhandled exception.  That's almost surely caused by eventArgs.Frame.Clone(), libraries that capture images only create a temporary bitmap that gets disposed again after the event is fired.  Use `new Bitmap(eventArgs.Frame)` instead so you make a deep copy.  And don't forget to dispose the old PictureBox1.Image or you'll quickly run out of memory.

Comment: Which, come to think of it, is the more likely way to get this code to crash.  So you need `If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then Dispose(PictureBox1.Image)` before the assignment.

Comment: i think your suggestion is the same as what i have on the code in my question now? and i did try to put the dispose before the assignment but same result

Comment: problem has been solved. thanks to all.